# JSON returning multiple columns, but all values as single string. How do I get matching key-value from array?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Here's my problem, I make an ajax call, get a response:

```
$.getJSON('fpCustom.cfc?method=getSysCounts',function(data){buildChart(data);});
```

I get a JSON reponse. Raw result:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ABC","DEF","GHI"],"DATA":[[11,27,4]]}"
```

When I ask for `COLUMN[0]`, I get correct value: `'ABC'`, but when I ask for `DATA[0]`, I get the whole `DATA` string: `11,27,4`. I think it probably has to do with the double square bracket, but don't know how to fix that.

How do I get `DATA[0]`, which should be `11`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the JSON:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ABC","DEF","GHI"],"DATA":[[11,27,4]]}"
```

The property `DATA` is an array of arrays.

Consider it like this: `DATA = [a, b, c]`, where `a`, `b` and `c` are variables. The thing is that your `a` is another array, just as `DATA` is.

This way `DATA[0]`, the first element of the `DATA` array, is an array.

> How do I get `DATA[0]`, which should be `11`?

The value you want is in: `DATA[0][0]`:

Because:

`DATA[0]` -> `[11,27,4]`

Then:

`DATA[0][0]` -> `11`
`DATA[0][1]` -> `27`
`DATA[0][2]` -> `4`

Comment: That worked, thanks. I didn't understand why it came back that way because I was only pulling one row of sums. After thinking about it I realized if I was returning multiple rows I probably would have seen that.

Comment: Yeah, probably instead of returning only one row, it was returning a set of rows with just one element (row).

Answer (score 0):

```
{"COLUMNS":["ABC","DEF","GHI"],"DATA":[[11,27,4]]}"
```

In COLUMNS is single dimentional array and DATA is two dimentional array so you have to access  value of DATA[i][j]

[check example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw9AZ/)